# how to merge duplicate rows using two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two rows from the dataframe below but at the same time I want to replace the `None` and `Nan` fields with values from the rows that have the values.
[image]

I started with

```
new_df = df.groupby(['source','code'], axis =0)
```

but the result wasn't what I am looking for. In the dataframe below I would row 2 and row 5 to merge into a single row and filled with non empty values

Comment: `df.groupby(['source','code'], axis =0).max()` or `df.groupby(['source','code'], axis =0).max()`?

Comment: If the rows are duplicate, `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: The rows aren't complete duplicates but the groupby fields in the code are the duplicate fields and I want to group them using these fields and if an empty field exists in one of the rows I would like to replace the empty field with the value from the non empty value from the other row

Comment: See if this works `df.groupby(['source', 'code']).pipe(bfill).pipe(first)`

Comment: @RichieV what are bfill and first ?

Comment: "I am trying to merge two rows " whicho rows? you can use to fill columns using`bfill` for nans, for none use replace to np.nan and then `bfill`

Comment: You can check them out in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html). They mean backfill and first row. Sygneto is right, it only works with NaN.

Comment: Thanks guys, will look into these two methods